# To prove a given set is an UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

The problem is to show that the set $R$ is an UFD, where

> $R := \{a\in \mathbb{Q}| a=\frac{n}{2^k} \text{ for some }n, k\in \mathbb{Z},k\geq0 \}$

I am thinking of something like $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(2x-1)$ but I cannot proceed from here.

Should I go through the definition of an UFD, that are

(1) unique factorization

(2) the Ascending Chain Condition?

If not, in general how could I show that a given set is an UFD? Since for other domains like ED and PID, the ideas are quite straight forward. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's a special case of [UFDs are preserved under localization](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/140584/242), where  $S$ (the denominator monoid) is that generated by $2$. Or, directly, you could extend (tweak) the proofs from $\Bbb Z$ after showing that the primes in $R$ are all the odd primes in $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: "how could I show that a given set is UFD?". See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1290781/about-the-ways-prove-that-a-ring-is-a-ufd), for example. It is of course again related to localisation.